# Design of data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Which do you suggest:

```
data Direction = Left | Right
type Direction = Bool
newtype Direction = Direction Bool
```

Then I'm making:

```
data Move = WalkRight Bool | Jump
```

or

```
data Move = Walk Direction | Jump
```

depending of the previous answer.
I have a function of type `Char -> Maybe Move`:

```
charToAction 'q' = Just $ WalkRight False
charToAction 'd' = Just $ WalkRight True
charToAction 'z' = Just Jump
charToAction _ = Nothing
```

Should I change my type `Move` into:

```
data Move = Stationary | WalkRight Bool | Jump
```

? The function would become:

```
charToAction 'q' = WalkRight False
charToAction 'd' = WalkRight True
charToAction 'z' = Jump
charToAction _ = Stationary
```

I wonder this because the list doesn't need a Maybe:

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Or is there a way to derive `Maybe` to make it cleaner?

Comment: `WalkRight False` isn't very suggestive of its intended meaning.

Comment: You're right. Which definition of Direction should I keep?

Comment: n.b. `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`, unlike what you've written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer something like:

```
data Direction = Left | Right
data Move = Walk Direction | Jump
type Action = Maybe Move
type ActionList = [Action]

charToAction :: Char -> Action
charToAction c = case c of
  'q' -> Just $ Walk Left
  'd' -> Just $ Walk Right
  'z' -> Just $ Jump
  _   -> Nothing

stringToActions :: String -> ActionList
stringToActions = map charToAction
```

under the principle that each data type clearly explains its own purpose, and doesn't "assume" anything about how it might be used. Some counter-examples:

```
newtype Direction = Direction Bool
data Move = Stationary | Walk Direction | Jump
```

Here, `Direction` doesn't really explain what it means... does it mean you have a direction or you don't have a direction? Hmmm! Also, what happens when you need `Up` and `Down`? It's hard to extend your program if `Direction` is just a `Bool`.

And `Move` has a data constructor `Stationary` here that isn't actually a move at all. You "leak" the notion that some keystrokes won't result in a move. Again that will end up complicating your code.

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks.
Are `type Action = Maybe Move` and `type ActionList = [Action]` a good habit? As for stringToActions (fun idea, BTW), it's just a curry, so is it worthy to define?
`And Move has a data constructor Stationary here that isn't actually a move at all.`. Well, lists are the same, `[]` is not really a list :P. And `0` is not really a quantity...
For `Walk`, I don't need `Up` or `Down` to be part of `Direction`, so I'll rename the type `DirectionX`.

Comment: Well, it all depends :) For `Stationary`, yeah, there might be other things (aside from char mapping) for which a `Stationary` move might also make sense. If you're making some kind of platform game, perhaps you could define `data Action = Move Move | Shoot Direction | Duck | Nothing`... Who knows! The most important thing is to model the data separately from the operations involving it.

Comment: Yes, type constructors and other functions :).

Comment: I'm not sure `ActionList` is a good type to make. Really, it says nothing more than `[Action]`, which, after all, literally means "list of Actions"! In this case, `[Action]` is also easier to read. Now, if you had a type with a more specific role than just a list of actions, like a list of possible actions to take, then I definitely see the case for something like `type ActionChoices = [Action]`. A type synonym is only good for providing additional information to the programmer, which "ActionList" does not do.

Comment: By similar reasoning to Tikhon Jelvis, I don't think `type Action = Maybe Move` is a good type synonym either.  I'd just use `Maybe Move` directly, since `Maybe` is such a common type that has so many utility functions for it.  Having the `[Maybe Move]` directly in the type signatures makes it easier for readers of the code to know what they can do with values of that type.

Comment: Wow, you don't event want to "assume" anything about how the word "assume" is understood.  That's pretty hardcore.